# Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) due to a background service

Tags: android, kotlin

The issue: around 10-15 seconds after the app's launch, it always crashes with the following:

```
D/ProfileInstaller: Installing profile for ge.edison.lockers
E/.edison.locker: Failed to open file '/data/data/ge.edison.lockers/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/dexopt/baseline.prof': No such file or directory
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 10014 (pool-3-thread-1), pid 8843 (.edison.lockers)
```

The application runs a background service and I noticed that disabling it resolves the issue. Code:

```
// MainActivity.kt:onViewCreated
...

val intent = Intent(activity, BackgroundService::class.java)

val connection = object : ServiceConnection {
    override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName?, service: IBinder?) {
        serviceMessenger = Messenger(service)
        val message = Message()
        message.replyTo = messenger
        serviceMessenger?.send(message)
        bound = true
    }

    override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName?) {
        serviceMessenger = null
        bound = false
    }
}

activity?.bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
```

BackgroundService.tk:

```
package ge.edison.lockers

import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.*

class BackgroundService : Service() {
    lateinit var mainHandler: Handler
    var messenger: Messenger? = null
    private val httpUtil: HTTPUtil = HTTPUtil()
    private var notificationManager: NotificationManager? = null

    private val incomingHandler = object : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
            messenger = msg.replyTo
            super.handleMessage(msg)
        }
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder {
        mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        mainHandler.post(connectionHealthTask)

        val mMessenger = Messenger(incomingHandler)
        return mMessenger.binder
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        showNotification()
        super.onCreate()
    }

    private val connectionHealthTask = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            if (State.connectionHandler != null) {
                State.connectionHandler!!.fetchStatus()
                logUSBHealth()
                logAPIHealth()
            }
            mainHandler.postDelayed(this, State.timeout.toLong())
        }
    }

    private fun logUSBHealth() {
        if (State.lastOutput.size < 9) return
        val percentage: Float =
            State.lastOutput.filter { status -> status }.size.toFloat() / State.lastOutput.size.toFloat() * 100
        if (percentage == 0F) {
            if (State.toBeDisconnected) State.connectionHandler = null
            else State.toBeDisconnected = true
        }
        val displayPercentage = if (percentage.isNaN()) "100%" else "${percentage.toInt()}%"

        val message = Message()
        message.obj = listOf(
            "USB connection health:",
            displayPercentage
        )
        messenger?.send(message)
        State.lastOutput.clear()
    }

    private fun logAPIHealth() {
        if (httpUtil.lastOutput.size < 9) return
        val percentage: Float =
            httpUtil.lastOutput.filter { status -> status in 200..299 }.size.toFloat() / httpUtil.lastOutput.size.toFloat() * 100
        if (percentage == 0F) {
            httpUtil.disconnected = if (httpUtil.disconnected == 0) 1 else 2
        }
        val displayPercentage = if (percentage.isNaN()) "100%" else "${percentage.toInt()}%"
        messenger?.send(
            Message.obtain(
                null, 0, listOf(
                    "API connection health:",
                    displayPercentage
                )
            )
        )
        httpUtil.lastOutput.clear()
    }

    private fun showNotification() {
        val text = "Service started"
        val notification: Notification =
            Notification.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setTicker(text) // the status text
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()) // the time stamp
                .setContentTitle("Service running") // the label of the entry
                .setContentText(text) // the contents of the entry
                .build()
        notificationManager?.notify(123, notification)
    }
}
```

More info:

- I'm new to Kotlin/Android development, I'm sorry if the issue is obvious. It's not to me.
- The app connects to an IoT device and periodically sends its status to an API endpoint.
- The issue happens regardless of `State.connectionHandler`, so the issue (probably) isn't related to the `connectionHealthTask` runnable.
- The issue persists even after removing the messenger/its handler from both the service and the main fragment.
- The issue persists even after removing the notification related code.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: SEGV means a segmentation fault.  The address is 0x0, which means a null pointer was dereferenced.  Seg faults only come from native code.  So someplace in your app either written in native code or calling native code is derefrencing a null pointer.  Beyond that you'd need to find the trace dump for more info.